# How to position the clicked item of ListView on top of the screen just after header in react native IOS app?

Tags: ios, listview, react-native, cardlayout

I am using ListView component. In my design, every item/row of listview can be expanded or collapsed when clicked. But only one item can remain in expanded state at a time.

The issue is, when I try to click any item from listview to expand, in some cases, some of its part is not visible until I scroll down. To show the full detail of expanded card on screen, I need to position the expanded card on top of the mobile screen just after my header. 
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new FlatList component: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html (Added in React Native 0.43).

It has the [scrollToItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/flatlist.html#scrolltoitem) method that will help you to do what you want.